# Drupal 8: How to use private file system for node

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, drupal-8

Scenario:
I want to create a field field and attach it to a content type and willing to store the uploaded file into private file system. 
I am using Drupal 8.6, php 7.1 and linux

My default file system is public, but for that specific file field, I want to store it, into private folder. So I created a folder outside my document root folder e.g. /var/www/private and set that into settings.php.

The purpose of this field is that, to allow, certain logged in users to able to download and restrict other.

I googled a lot, there are lot of suggestions, none worked or pointed the issue I am facing. I set the file directory as "dcouments/[date:custom:Y]-[date:custom:m]".

Now when i trying to upload a file, it gives me error like, folder "documents/2018-09" can't be created and upload failed. Surely it seems permission issue, i gave "private" folder to "rwxrwxr-x" permission, but its not working. Strangely it works in windows system.

Could anyone suggest, how to fix that? Whats going wrong there?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I actually find out that, the web-server don't have permission to create sub-directory in the private folder.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions you defined may just be fine. The problem maybe that the private folder doesn't belong to www-data neither to its group. Check the real owner of the folder and set it to www-data. This should do the trick.

Comment: Nope, its not worked. I set the same owner / group name of drupal folders.

Comment: Can you make an `ls -la` on your sites/default/ directory and on the parent directory of private directory, just to see what is shown ?